# flask: why cant I import from .views or .models in __init__.py?

Tags: python, flask

When I try to import views from .views, it gives me the error saying 'attempted relative import with no known parent package.
It does the same thing when I try to import Users from .models

here is the code

```
from .views import views #NOT WORKING
app.register_blueprint(views, url_prefix='/')

    
from .models import Users #not working either
createdatabase(app)
```

I am a beginner programmer and is trying to make a website using flask and python. I have searched but don't know how to solve this issue. If you do know how to please help me. Thanks

Comment: You need to add the structure of your app/project folder to your question

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow :)

I usually put all my code files into one parent folder (I usually call it `src`) and then make subfolders from there if needed. I think python doesn't allow relative imports when it is directly in the root folder (please correct me if I'm wrong). Also keep in mind, that **all** your folders that contain python scripts (that you want to import anywhere else in your program) need to have a `__init__.py` file. It can be empty and it's just a somewhat magical way to tell python in which folders to look for scripts.

Comment: Do I need to put __init__.py files in template and static folder where my html and css is kept?

Comment: No, only where you have .py files :)

Comment: Hi, I just fixed the problem. Realized my main script needed to be outside the folder with my __init__.py and views.py scripts in order to run properly. Also mixed up the blueprints. Thanks for your help. You can tell that I'm really a beginner when I do not even know how to organize my folders . Small mistake and I will try to avoid it in the future.